# Processing audio file with python or php

Tags: php, python, algorithm, audio

I'm trying to find a library for Php or Python that could process audio files. I need to loop through recorded phone calls and process them to remove those that have some specific pattern e.g. beep tone only instead of human voice. I think it would be possible by comparing samples of amplitudes in audio file. Are there any libraries you know of that could help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Python comes with the standard library [wave](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html) module that can load and parse .wav files; detecting beep tones is probably a little harder than you think, but not prohibitively difficult.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already trying SOX library but will take a look at wave as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Audiolab](http://cournape.github.com/audiolab/) is a python library which can load AIFF, AU and WAV files directly into a [numpy](http://www.numpy.org) array.

It is likely that audio containing only beep tones will have a fairly simple [power spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_spectrum), which can be obtained from the audio array using `numpy.fft`.

Answer (score 0):

Someone recommends me the [pyaudiere](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyaudiere/0.2), it can "pass sound buffers as NumPy arrays of float32's". I never used it before, you may give it a go.

I used to use [pymad](http://spacepants.org/src/pymad/), it might be a little old buy very handy.